# Fill a resizable UIView with a transparent plain color that sticks to bounds

Tags: ios

I have a UIImageView in a UIView.

```
media.mediaImageView = [UIImageView new];
media.mediaImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

media.mediaImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 120);
media.mediaImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
media.mediaImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.tableView addSubview:media.mediaImageView];
```

I would like to add a layer (or something else, a view ?) to that UIView, this layer would be filled with a plain color with alpha transparency. In the following example it would be redColor and transparency 0.5 :

[image]

But later in code the UIView is resized :

```
rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
myUIView.frame = rect;
```

**The color layer should automatically cover the entire UIView (whatever its size) without explicitly redrawing the layer.** Is this possible ?

I can make it work but only by redrawing the UIView AND the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough. Add a subview to your image view. Set this view's background to the desired color. Set it's frame to match the image view's bounds. And be sure to set this view's `autoresizingMask` to have both flexible width and height. That will ensure it resizes automatically when the image view's size changes.

```
media.mediaImageView = [UIImageView new];
media.mediaImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

media.mediaImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 120);
media.mediaImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
media.mediaImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

// create and add overlay
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:media.mediaImageView.bounds];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5]; // as needed
overlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[media.mediaImageView addSubview:overlay];
```